# Reading text file with C program cause processor to run at 100%

Tags: c, linux, file, gcc, fgets

I'm trying to create a dictionary for a little text-line game.
I coded the file reading part assuming that the number of lines in the file is unknown, so I make it read the entire file one time at the beginning of the execution to count the lines.
The final goal would be to make it chose a random word in the file for treatment, putting it in a dynamically allocated pointer.

Here's the code of the reading part :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <time.h>

//declaration des fonctions :

void main(void){


//Declaration des variables :

unsigned char *motSecret=NULL;   //mot à trouver
unsigned char *motAffich=NULL;       //mot à afficher
unsigned char vide[]="****************************"; //chaine servant à initialisation affichage
unsigned char taille=0,saisie=0,essais=10,flag1=0,flag2=0,i=0,n=0; //variables et compteurs divers
int aleat=0;
FILE *dico=NULL;  //variable qui lit le fichier
srand(time(NULL));

//initialisation du mot aleatoire :

dico=fopen("dico.txt","r");     //ouvre le fichier en lecture
if(dico==NULL)  //gueule si ça n'a pas marché
{printf("###FATAL ERROR : FILE EXPECTED BUT RETURNED NULL###"); exit(0);}
else
{
    while((n=fgetc(dico))!=EOF)
    {
        if(n=='\n') taille++;  //compte le nombre de lignes
    }
fclose(dico);
}
}
```

When executing that, the program freezes, like it was handling an unlimited loop, and the processor is immediately used at 100%, until I force it to stop with ctrl+c.

I'm compiling and running that on Linux, with gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) 5.4.0 20160609.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: You're basically asking us to debug for you. Pick a debugger, give it a try and if you still have a specific question come back. (et les commentaires en français c'est pas top ;) )

Comment: `printf("###FATAL ERROR : FILE EXPECTED BUT RETURNED NULL###"); exit(0);` . If a fatal error occurred, why are you exiting with a value of 0. (Which indicates no error).  Why is that message not being written to stderr?  What was the cause of the error?  Which file? `if(dico==NULL) { perror("dico.txt"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}`

Comment: @WilliamPursell I just wrote that like that, to force exiting when problem occur, I don't need the return value for what I'm doing, and I didn't knew about perror()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined

```
unsigned char n;
```

and so the loop

```
while((n=fgetc(dico))!=EOF)
```

will never terminate because the value of `n` is never `-1`. You have an infinite loop which is attempting to read past the end of the file.

Function `fgetc` returns an `int` value so you should have

```
int n;
```